# Conjugate roots of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

If $\sqrt 2 -  i$ is a root of $x^5-x^4-2x^3+mx^2+9x+m-11=0$, $m \in \Bbb Q$ find m and the other roots.
My question is what other roots can i deduce from what is given?
Is $\sqrt 2 + i$ the only one i can deduce or are $-\sqrt 2 -  i$ and $-\sqrt 2 +  i$ also "valid" (by valid i mean deducible without knowing the answer).

More generally if i have natural coefficient polynomial with a given a root like $\sqrt a + bi$ can i say that $\sqrt a -  bi$, $-\sqrt a + bi$ and $-\sqrt a -  bi$ are also roots?

Comment: If $a=\sqrt2-i\implies(a-\sqrt2)^2=(-i)^2\iff a^2-2\sqrt2a+5=0$

Squaring 
$$(a^2+5)^2=(2\sqrt2 a)^2\iff a^4+2a^2+25=0$$

Comment: @lab, it should be $a^4-2a^2+9=0$.